# How to use Readmore.js?

Tags: javascript, read-more

I am trying to use [Readmore.js](http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/) for WooCommerce category description "Read more / Close" functionality. I enqueue the JavaScript and add `$('article').readmore();` in the "Insert Header and Footer" plugin, but when the page loads, it gives me this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
   (anonymous function) @ (index):205
   j @ jquery.js:2
   k.fireWith @ jquery.js:2
   m.extend.ready @ jquery.js:2
   J @ jquery.js:2
```

Where have I made a mistake and what is the right way to use this JS file in WordPress?

I know how to use it in a simple HTML page, but in WordPress it looks like it's a different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to wordpress loading jquery in noconflict mode in which the $ shortcut does not work. Try to replace it with an explicit jQuery or wrapt the relevant code in a way which will decalre $ like in the following example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('article').readmore();
});
```

Comment: I know, but when i use the way you suggested i get the following error : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).readmore is not a function.should i change the readmore.js at some point to make it work with Wordpress Jquery?

Comment: hmm, I see. I know that I would chane the readmore source, but maybe defining $ in global scope like `(function($) {
})( jQuery );` should work? never tried it myself

Comment: IIRC the way I do it is just replace all $ with jQuery untill the errors go away. Not very "guru" of me, I know ;)

Comment: Thanks Mark, i had made a goofy mistake in enqueue the first answer works